# Is it possible to redirect cell output in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, reveal.js

I am using jupyter and jupyter-nbconvert to create a html presentation. However, I have some cells that produce an output image that I want to share on a separate slide. Is it possible to redirect the output of one cell to its own slide?

Comment: See the note in this section, you need to configure this from notebook interface: http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reveal-js-html-slideshow

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using Damian Vila's Jupyter extension [RISE](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE). It provides some of the control you need for how cells are displayed in slides.

It is flagged by the latest Jupyter (3.6) as possibly not compatible, but I've seen no problems using it so far.